# Double.compare method is not getting recognised in sonarQube and is giving division by zero bug

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
double Sales = 0.0;
double var = 0.0;
double varPercent = 0.0;

if(Double.compare(Sales, 0) != 0) varPercent = var / Sales;
```

My code snippet looks something like this. This method is being used to check whether Sales is equal to zero or not before the division is done. But I still get a Critical bug for this in Sonaqube (Division by Zero bug). Is this a code error from my side or something else?

Comment: Why not just `if(Sales != 0.0)`?

Comment: That isn't a recommended way for comparing the Double Values in Java. If you check the various docs for comparing double values, its suggested not to directly compare it.

Comment: "If you check the various docs for comparing double values" can you provide links? You want to avoid using `==` with `double` when there's a possibility of `NaN`; if you've got NaN in `Sales`, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: BTW, the above code works ok in eclipse.

Comment: *That isn't a recommended way...* - How about sticking with proper java naming conventions.

Comment: @ScaryWombat the question is not whether the code works, the question is why SonarQube is saying there's a critical bug in there.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Maybe that is why I said **BTW**

Comment: If you initialize Sales with -0 (`double Sales = -0.0;`) then with your code you will get `NaN` as a result, because `Double.compare()` distinguishes between 0.0 and -0.0. If you would write `if(Sales != 0.0)` then the result would be 0.0